# Is it possible to utilize multiple bottom borders in Vue/Vuetify specifically within the v-card component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, styles, vuetify.js

See the image here of the goal :

[image: See image here of the goal]

I need to add 3 bottom borders to my `v-card` component and am having trouble doing so.

I have tried:

- using 'border-style: double'
- using box-shadow and border combined
- adding outer divs with bottom-borders
- positioning, what a mess

Everything I try looks awful and feels so hacky. What is the correct way to add this 3 border setup to the bottom of a Vuetify `v-card` component?

Comment: Did you try just adding 3 v-divider elements? Maybe with a bit of top margin for each of the 3 to separate them

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I did try using v-dividers but they inherit the paddding that you see with the other attributes (Start, State, etc.). If I can extend the v-divider to take up 100% of the v-card width that would work, but not sure how to do that. Thanks for your idea

Answer (score 1):

You could add a couple `v-divider` inside the `v-card`, and give them vertical margins:

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    ...

    <!-- special bottom border lines -->
    <v-divider />
    <v-divider />
  </v-card>
</template>

<style>
.v-divider {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QWEXKbR)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove the padding and margin from the v-card and ul. That meant I had to apply it to each li and not to the final li that housed the v-dividers. So there is a little repeated code with all the class="px-6" assignments on each li instead of the overall v-card, but it allowed me to single out that last li and utilize all the real estate in the v-card.

Winner, winner, chicken (veggie) dinner